# Какие индексы можно подобрать для выборки MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

На странице есть:

подсчет общего кол-ва объявлений (для пагинации)

```
select count(*) from bazardnua_advert advert where advert.hide='show' and advert.end_putdate > 1481317200
```

выборка (имена таблиц в  select заменил на *, чтоб место не занимали)

```
select * from bazardnua_advert advert where advert.hide='show' and advert.end_putdate > 1481317200 order by advert.sort_time DESC limit 0 , 10
```

1. advert.hide  (hide или show) - скрыто ли объявление  (данное поле меняется, если объявление просрочено)
2. end_putdate - дата окончания объявления (поле меняется, если объявление было продлено)

**Генерация страницы (530тыс.объявлений):**

1. без индексов  - 2.4 секунды
2. уник и неуник .состав.индекс (hide,end_putdate) - 2.7 секунды,
   не используется end_putdate
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. обычный индекс (end_putdate) - 3.4 секунды[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в моем случае мне индексы хоть какие-то смогут помочь  или тут нужно смотреть в другом направлении ?

Может нужны другие варианты индексов? Может нужно добавить в выборку какую-то колонку ? Что посоветуете ?

Спасибо за ответы .

Comment: Слова и скриншоты не соответствуют друг другу. И где DDL таблицы?

Comment: добавьте индексы и посмотрите насколько быстрее будет работать, итить! не?

Comment: hide/show значения имхо заменить на 0/1

Comment: @Jean-Claude А какой, по-твоему, у него тип сейчас? если думаешь, что варчар, то попытайся объяснить, как на скриншоте появляется keylen = 2... который на следующем скриншоте уже = 5. Впрочем, скриншоты там непонятно от чего, это я уже говорил.

Comment: **hide** - это просто название индекса (hide,end_putdate)

и во  втором скрине такое же имя , но индекс другой

Comment: @Sarkis Allahverdian Это как раз понятно, что индексы разные, и нам предложено самим догадаться, какие именно. Хотя непонятно, почему 2 байта... да и тип поля так и остаётся невыясненным. А это важно. Как важна и версия сервера. А также хотелось бы знать, где предел тех изменений, на который Вы готовы пойти ради увеличения производительности именно этого запроса.

Comment: **hide** - enum('show', 'hide') null
**end_putdate** - int unsigned null

Версия сервера: 5.5.49-0+deb7u1   

Данный вопрос для меня носит ознакомительный характер исключительно для изучения индексов .

Был залит движок и база для своих тестов

Comment: Угу... подозрения подтвердились... ещё один вопрос - каково соотношение возвращённого запросом числа записей к общему их количеству в таблице? намёк: если это больше, чем ~20%, то использование индексов на деле только увеличит время обработки запроса.

Comment: смотрите, у меня база тестовая , т.е чтобы ее увеличит до 500 тыс я просто копировал записи с 1тыс до 500 , но при этом **hide**  у меня везде show ,а **end_putdate**  я сделал у всех разным  (mysql циклом увеличивал на +1+2+3+4 и т.д)

При выборке : у меня 100% записей . 
Может мои все действия не оправдываются потому, что я делаю опыты не на "живой" базе, а просто дублированной ?